# JMeter Dashboard Report for multiple threads

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

Is there a way to edit the filter property in user.property file to display multiple threads. If i edit it for 1 thread it works fine for me , but i am not sure how to edit it for multiple threads.

Basically i want the APDEX to display both the threads. The attached image is just 1 thread being displayed.

.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could add thread number at the end of the sampler label to make the distinguished from each other.

[${__threadNum}](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum)

For example 
[image]